# Java Cucumber Using Keys From Property File In Examples Table

Tags: java, selenium, automation, cucumber, properties-file

Its been a long time since I have worked with Scenario Outlines. What I wanted to achieve was to reference keys from my config_data.properties file in the Examples table, so that I have once source of truth for content/data for my tests.

I have been getting an error on the steps that need to get the data from the properties file and the value that gets entered into the first name text box when I run my test is firstName1 not the value in the properties file. The error in question:

```
[31morg.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: keys should be a 
string
```

Here is what I have:

Feature File:

```
@new_test
Scenario Outline: User fills out the Personal Info Form With Valid Data
And I enter a first name as "<first_name>"
And I enter a middle name as "<middle_name>"
And I enter a last name as "<last_name>"



Examples:

|first_name | middle_name | last_name | 
|firstName1 | middlename1 | lastname1 |
```

Step Definitions: (I think this is where the problem is)

```
public class PersonalInfoFormSteps {

    private PersonalInfoFormPage personalInfo;

    private DataReader data;

    @When("^I enter a first name as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_enter_a_first_name_as(String first_name) throws Throwable {
    personalInfo.getFirstNameField().click();
    data.loadData().getProperty(first_name);
    personalInfo.getFirstNameField().sendKeys(first_name);

    }
}
```

DataReader.class (This works fine for getting data that does not involve scenario outline)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject;

public class DataReader extends PageObject {

WebDriverWait wait = null;
private WebDriver driver;

String result = "";
InputStream inputStream;
File file = new File(
        "file path to properties file goes here");

public DataReader(WebDriver driver) {
    super();
}

public Properties loadData() throws IOException {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fileInput = null;
    try {
        fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // load properties file
    try {
        prop.load(fileInput);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return prop;
}
```

}

Properties File Data:

```
firstName1: Mickey
middleName1: M
lastName1: Mouse
```

Answer (score 1):

Haha figured it out. I changed the code in the step definition:

```
@And("^I enter a first name as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void i_enter_a_first_name_as(String first_name) throws Throwable {
    personalInfo.getFirstNameField().click();

    personalInfo.getFirstNameField()
            .sendKeys(data.loadData().getProperty(first_name));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Step Definition is wrong, 
replace this line :

```
@When("^I enter a first name as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
```

by this line

```
@And("^I enter a first name as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
```

Or replace this line :

```
And I enter a first name as "<first_name>"
```

By this line

```
When I enter a first name as "<first_name>"
```

Comment: That did not solve the problem in question, it does not care about And or When when reading the data from the properties file. To clarify my issue is that in the example table instead of hard coding "John" as a first name, I want to pass a key in my properties file in the Examples table.

Comment: Cucumber does care about And, When and Then if there is no method matching your scenario, cucumber will tell you that a scenario does not exist

Comment: That was not the issue here and no it did not tell me that scenario did not exist. As you can see above I fixed my problem.